# Your Kindle is unable to connect at this time

Tags: kindle, amazon, hardware, kindle-cloud-reader, wifi

Dealing with a new used [K3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Kindle#Kindle_Keyboard) keyboard Kindle, it connects wirelessly and will even connect to Google for search results.

However, whenever I try to login it gives an error that the wireless network isn't available.  Might this be indicative of a hardware failure?

Can login to the cloud interface fine from a PC.

The [error](https://www.theverge.com/2016/3/20/11271880/amazon-kindle-emergency-update-unable-to-connect-at-this-time):

> Your Kindle is unable to connect at this time. Please make sure you
>   are within wireless range and try again. If the problem persists,
>   please restart your Kindle from the Menu in Settings and try again.

the OS is version 3.4, less than the 3.4.2 which is [required](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=202048000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Amazon Device Support  › Fire & Kindle Software Updates› Kindle
>   Keyboard Software Updates
>
> The latest software version for Kindle Keyboard is 3.4.2. This update
>   automatically downloads and installs on your Kindle Keyboard when
>   connected wirelessly; however, you can also manually download the
>   software and transfer the update to your device via USB cable.
>
> The software update includes general bug fixes. Download Kindle
>   Keyboard Software Updates
>
> Determine the current software version on your Kindle Keyboard before
>   downloading and installing a software update. For more information, go
>   to Determine Your Software Version.
>
> Depending on your current software update version, you may have to
>   install a previous software update before installing the latest
>   version. Select one of the links below to download the software update
>   file directly to your computer.
>
> Important: If you copy multiple software update files to your device
>   at the same time, the software update will not be successful. Please
>   fully install one file, and then download and install the next file,
>   as appropriate. If you have...    Do this...
>
> Kindle Keyboard Wi-Fi
>
> ...
>
> ```
> If you have software version 3.4.1, download Software Update 3.4.2.
> If you have software version 3.4, download Software Update 3.4.2.
> ```

source:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200529700